# Get endpoint of line based on beginpoint, angle and magnitude in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, line

Problem: I can only draw line with matplotlib when I have the endpoint and beginpoint of a given line.

In my case I'm missing the endpoint but I do have information about the Angle and the magnitude.

What's the best way to implement this line?

Comment: are you asking about the math or the programming? How would you do it with a pencil and paper?

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate the endpoint coordinates:

```
x1 = x0 + magnitude * np.cos(angle)
y1 = y0 + magnitude * np.sin(angle)
```